# document.getElementByClassName and then post between 2 divs inside

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way to get the only post with a class 'selected' and then insert a div inside/between other divs? I am basically posting images to my websites timeline and now I am trying to group a whole bunch of images posted on the same date, but the way the site is structured is that it pulls info from the database and then outputs it into XML. I am pulling that XML information via AJAX / JQuery and then depending on the type, it posts differently (different layouts) as in 1 type for typed / content posts, one for image posts, and so on. Now as I said, I need to group the images on the same date.

Here is my code so far:

```
function post_cat_image(postid, postaccount_name, postauthor, posttype, postdata, postdate, profileimg, postdatefordisplay, postapplauds){
post_image_dates[counter] = postdate;

if($.inArray(postdate, post_image_dates)){
    var posts = $(".year");
    posts.removeClass("selected");
    var slt;
    var matchedPost = posts.filter("[data-date='" + postdate + "']");
    if(matchedPost.length > 0){
        matchedPost.addClass("selected");
        slt = document.getElementByClassName('selected');
var more_post_content = document.createElement('div');
    more_post_content.id = 'more_post_content';

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><img src="' + postdata + '"/></a>';

    ul.appendChild(li);
    more_post_content.appendChild(ul);
var slt = document.getElementById("selected");

        if(slt && slt.length){
          slt[0].appendChild(more_post_content);
        }
    }




    slt.appendChild(more_post_content);

    return 0;
} else {

var timeline_item = document.createElement('div');
timeline_item.className = "timeline-item";

timeline_item.setAttribute('data-date', postdate);

var year = document.createElement('div');
year.className = "year";
year.innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + postdatefordisplay + '</a>';

year.setAttribute('data-date', postdate);


var marker = document.createElement('span');
marker.className = "marker";

var type = document.createElement('span');
type.className = "post_comment";

marker.appendChild(type);
year.appendChild(marker);
timeline_item.appendChild(year);

var info = document.createElement('div');
info.className = 'info';

var main = document.createElement('div');
main.className = 'main';

var image = document.createElement('div');
image.id = 'image';
if(profileimg == ''){
    profileimg = 'images/profiles/profile.jpg'
}
image.innerHTML = '<a href="timeline.php?user=' + postaccount_name + '"><img style="width:50px;" src="'+ profileimg +'" /></a>';

var cont = document.createElement('div');
cont.id = "cont";
cont.innerHTML = '<h3><a href="timeline.php?user=' + postaccount_name + '">'+ postauthor +'</a></h3>';

var post_content = document.createElement('div');
post_content.id = 'post_content';

var image_post_content = document.createElement('div');
image_post_content.id = 'image_post_content';
image_post_content.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><img id="main_image" src="' + postdata + '"</a>';

var more_post_content = document.createElement('div');
more_post_content.id = 'more_post_content';


var clear = document.createElement('div');
clear.className = 'clearfix';

var clear2 = document.createElement('div');
clear2.className = 'clearfix';

var clear3 = document.createElement('div');
clear3.className = 'clearfix';

var comm_app = document.createElement('div');
comm_app.id = 'comm_app';
comm_app.innerHTML = '<ul><li><a href="#" class="applause" onclick="applause(' + postaccount_name + ')">Applaud(' + postapplauds + ')</a></li></ul>';


main.appendChild(image);
main.appendChild(cont);
main.appendChild(clear);
post_content.appendChild(image_post_content);
main.appendChild(post_content);
main.appendChild(clear2);
main.appendChild(clear3);
main.appendChild(comm_app);

info.appendChild(main);

timeline_item.appendChild(info);
document.getElementById('timeline').appendChild(timeline_item);

counter++;
}
}
```

But I am getting an error when trying to get the class, and I don't think I am doing it right to group the images together?

This is the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'slt.appendChild')
```

I am new to JavaScript, JQuery and AJAX, but I have a bit more experience in PHP - still not much, only a few months so sorry for any mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementByClassName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a Node.

You must select an item, e.g.:

```
if(slt && slt.length){
  slt[0].appendChild(more_post_content);
}
```

Comment: But it says that slt is undefined?

Comment: then `matchedPost.length` must be 0

Comment: `matchedPost` is not 0, it has got data inside of it and the length is 1. So why is sly returning `undefined`?

Comment: when  `matchedPost.length` wouldn't be 0, `slt` couldn't be undefined, because getElementsByClassName always returns a NodeList(also when there aren't nodes with the particular class). So the only reason why `slt` is `undefined` could be that  `(matchedPost.length > 0)` is not `true`

Comment: if `(matchedPost.length > 0)` is false, it wouldn't run the code. that's how an if statement works

Comment: That's what I say, `slt` can only be undefined when the code inside the if-condition doesn't run. However, you don't need to tell me how an `if` works, I'm familiar with JS for 15 years(FYI: `if` is not a *statement*, it's a *condition*).